# Spring Kafka transaction commit sequence

Tags: spring-kafka, spring-transactions

I have two services. User calls Service-A's REST endpoint, which does the processing, creates record/entry in the database, and then sends a Kafka event so that Service-B can be consumed.

I have annotated with @Transactional so that the database commit and Kafka commit happens at the same time.

Service-B will receive the Kafka event, process, and send back the updated event to Service-A.

In such a scenario, I am seeing that certain updates are getting failed in Service-A stating that record/entry is not found. Is it a Race condition?

As [ChainedKafkaTransactionManager](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-kafka/issues/1699) is deprecated how can I make sure that the database commit happens first and then the Kafka commit?

"For producer-initiated transactions, with transaction synchronization, the Kafka commit will also occur after the DB." from Gary Russell

In my scenario, as the transaction is not initiated by Kafka how can I reverse the commits?

```
@Transactional("dstm")
public void someMethod(String in) {
  Employee employee = this.repository.save(new Employee(in));
  if(employee.isSomeCondition()) {
    sendToKafka(employee);
  }
}
```

Comment: I am facing same issue with my project. How you were able to fix it ? Can you please mention your solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually there is a good example how you can configure the transaction handling over several datasources here: https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/current/reference/html/#ex-jdbc-sync

another problem that might cause the problem is the isolation level of your consumers. have you changed it to read_committed?

Comment: Even in those examples as well I see that Kafka commit is happening first. In my case, I need to create a new record and if it is of a certain type then I need to notify another system.

Comment: in a producer initiated tx you have full control over the tx ordering. this is actually not kafka specific. what you can do is to debug your application and check if the kafka tx is started before the db transaction. chech for transactionIntercepor and verify that the corresponding plattformTransactionManager

Comment: In my case transaction is initiated by the data source transaction manager, updated question with sample code. I cant initiate transactions with the Kafka transaction manager as in certain conditions won't even send a message/event.

Comment: If you want the Kafka transaction to commit first, use a local transaction. See KafkaTemplate.executeInTransaction().

Comment: @GaryRussell I want to commit the DB transaction first to avoid the race condition(DB commit is still going on and response for the event is already received and to process that event record is still not available in database)

Comment: That is the default behavior with transaction synchronization.